# Project seems to be using two different RVM Gemsets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I created a project a number of years ago using Rails 4, then some time later I upgraded to Rails 5 and used a different Gemset (ruby-2.4.1@PM-Planner vs ruby-2.4.1@PM-Planner-Rails5). Today I finally got around to deleting (on my dev machine, of course) the old Gemset. However, when I fired up the test server I got an error that shows the app still using the old Gemset:

```
File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets.
Load paths:
  /home/wucolin/src/PMPlanner/app/assets/images
  /home/wucolin/src/PMPlanner/app/assets/javascripts
  /home/wucolin/src/PMPlanner/app/assets/stylesheets
  /home/wucolin/src/PMPlanner/lib/assets/stylesheets
  /home/wucolin/src/PMPlanner/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /home/wucolin/src/PMPlanner/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@PM-Planner-Rails5/gems/best_in_place-3.1.1/lib/assets/javascripts
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@PM-Planner-Rails5/gems/best_in_place-3.1.1/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@PM-Planner-Rails5/gems/jquery-rails-4.3.3/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@PM-Planner-Rails5/gems/actioncable-5.2.2.1/lib/assets/compiled
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@PM-Planner-Rails5/gems/activestorage-5.2.2.1/app/assets/javascripts
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@PM-Planner-Rails5/gems/actionview-5.2.2.1/lib/assets/compiled
  /home/wucolin/src/PMPlanner/node_modules
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@PM-Planner/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/assets/javascripts
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@PM-Planner/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/assets/stylesheets
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@PM-Planner/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/assets/images
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@PM-Planner/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/assets/fonts
```

I verified that bootstrap-sprockets.js is in the new gemset but the error messages seems to indicate RoR isn't even looking there for the file!

When I restore the ruby-2.4.1@PM-Planner gemset directory everything works fine.

In my project root directory I have .ruby-gemset that contains the string "PM-Planner-Rails5".

Any idea where that reference to the old gemset is coming from? I thought rvm was supposed to keep all gemsets separate and independent.

Comment: It's worth noting that gemsets are largely irrelevant now that [Bundler](https://bundler.io) exists. If you're having trouble with them you might want to just remove them.

Comment: You mean not use gemsets at all? Just delete the .ruby-gemset file?

Comment: That's my idea. I have never had to use them. Came close a few times, but then Bundler arrived and saved the day. With Bundler you should be able to, at the worst, `bundle exec` things and get the right versions.

Comment: OK. I'll give that a shot. Thanks.

Comment: So I've removed .ruby-gemset from the project root but it still seems to be looking for resources in the ruby-2.4.1@PM-Planner gemset. Could I have somehow misconfigured rvm when I started out?

Comment: You could always `rvm implode` and start over if you have no luck [switching default gemsets](https://rvm.io/gemsets/using).

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing! Seems way back when, I had added the path to the ruby-2.4.1@PM-Planner gemset to the config.assets.path for the project. Not sure why - probably had issue with not being able to find the bootstrap-sprockets.js file, like now. So, this is now a different problem. Case closed!

Comment: That's an unusual sort of situation to be in, but good that you got to the bottom of it. You may want to add a self-answer with the specific fix as this may help someone else in the same jam, perhaps even yourself in the future.

Comment: Not yet. I need to figure out how to load bootstrap-sockets.js without having to manually add its location to the assets load path. *That* is the real fix.